# How to extract objects from a csv / pandas dataframe of JSON files?

Tags: python, json

I have a csv (which I turned into a `pandas` dataframe) in which each row consists of a different `JSON` file, each `JSON` file has the exact same format and objects as the others, and each one represents a unique transaction (purchase) I would like to take this dataframe and convert it into a dataframe or excel file in which each column would represent an object from the `JSON` file and each row would represent each transaction.

The `JSON` also contains arrays, in which case I would like to be able to retrieve each element of the array. Ideally I would like to be able to retrieve all possible objects from the `JSON` files and turn them into columns.

A simplified version of a row would be:

```
    {  
       "source":{  
          "analyze":true,
          "billing":{  
             "gender":null,
             "name":"xxxxx",
             "phones":[  
                {  
                   "area_code":"xxxxx",
                   "country_code":"xxxxx",
                   "number":"xxxxx",
                   "phone_type":"xxxxx"
                }
             ]
          },
          "created_at":"xxxxx",
          "customer":{  
             "address":{  
                "city":"xxxxx",
                "complement":"xxxxx",
                "country":"xxxxx",
                "neighborhood":"xxxxx",
                "number":"xxxxx",
                "state":"xxxxx",
                "street":"xxxxx",
                "zip_code":"xxxxx"
             },
             "date_of_birth":"xxxxx",
             "documents":[  
                {  
                   "document_type":"xxxxx",
                   "number":"xxxxx"
                }
             ],
             "email":"xxxxx",
             "gender":xxxxx,
             "name":"xxxxx",
             "number_of_previous_orders":xxxxx,
             "phones":[  
                {  
                   "area_code":"xxxxx",
                   "country_code":"xxxxx",
                   "number":"xxxxx",
                   "phone_type":"xxxxx"
                }
             ],
             "register_date":xxxxx,
             "register_id":"xxxxx"
          },
          "device":{  
             "ip":"xxxxx",
             "lat":"xxxxx",
             "lng":"xxxxx",
             "platform":xxxxx,
             "session_id":xxxxx
          }
    }
    }
```

And my python code,,,

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"<name of csv file in which each row is a JSON file>")
```

A simplified of my expected output would be something like

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zztuo.png)

Comment: What exactly is the output you are expecting? What do you mean each row contains a "json file"? Do you mean each row in your "csv" is a valid JSON string? IOW, it's simply a text file of valid JSON strings separated by newlines?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Yes that's exactly what I mean, each row of my dataframe's first column (or each cell in the A column of my excel/csv file) is a valid JSON string in the format above.

I would like to know if it is possible to extract objects from each of these JSON strings and put them in another dataframe, I will edit my post above.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried anything? Have you looked up how to use json in Python? If so, what difficulties did you encounter? It generally helps if you give a small example of your input and what the corresponding output would be.

Comment: Hey man, I've edited my post! I have tried to look up this information here on stack overflow but to no avail so far, I'll keep looking, if you could refer me somewhere I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this as the output, for example to get area_code:

```
        A_col                                          area_code
0   {"source":{"analyze":true,"billing":{"gender":...   xxxxx
```

first:

**`"gender":xxxxx, "number_of_previous_orders":xxxxx, "register_date":xxxxx,              "platform":xxxxx, "session_id":xxxxx,` should be double quoted**

get the json document:

```
newjson = []
with open('./example.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        newjson.append(line)
```

format it to string:

```
jsonString = ''.join(newjson)
```

turn into python object:

```
jsonData = json.loads(jsonString)
```

extract the fields using dictionary operations and turn into pandas dataframe:

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame({"A_col": jsonString, "area_code": jsonData['source']['billing']['phones'][0]['area_code']}, index=[0])
```